# Ceate dynamic generic type in c#

Tags: c#

I have made a generic class like below:

```
public abstract class ListCoreDTO<T=int, P=int, G=int, S=int>
{      
   public T Value { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public P ParentID { get; set; }

   public G Group { get; set; }
   public string DetailsInfo { get; set; }
   public S SerialNo { get; set; }
}
```

Here I want calling my generic class like below:

```
public class ListGenericDTO : ListCoreDTO<T:int, S:long>
{

}
```

How can I make this type of generic class and my calling class?

Comment: I do not really understand the problem. Do you want the inheriting class to be generic as well? And thus want to use the generic arguments for accessing the base-class?

Comment: The "calling class"(ListGenericDTO) is the "inheriting class"

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht, you can make a solution by java or c#, its up to you.

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht, i want to pass optional generic type parameter.

Comment: There are no such things as an optional generic type argument.

Comment: Either remove `P` and `G` from the base class, or make `ListGenericDTO` a generic class, as in Patriks answer. Other than that, your question is quite vague - what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, did not you understand? need optional parameter in generic type.

Comment: No, that was not clear from your question. Either way, what you want is not possible in C#, but maybe there's an alternative approach that does do what you need. What did you want to use this for?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question, you want to create another generic type which uses some arguments fix and some variable.

When I'm correct, your class signature should look like this

```
public class ListGenericDTO<P, G> : ListCoreDTO<int, P, G, long>
```

So the `ListCoreDTO`-type gets typed with `int`for `T` and `long` for `S`.

Comment: In that case, I have no idea what you want or what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an optional generic argument. This is a limitation of the language an something you simply need to workaround.

One way to do such a workaround is to implement inherited classes which fix the generic argument one way or another (see answer from Patrik Eckebrecht). This will allow you to call the generic class as if it had optional arguments, although it will behave with the semantics of a derived class when it comes to using the types.